# How to visualize sticker inside a canvas using a lib external

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas, draw

I am developing an application that uses a lib for the canvas and another lib to add sticker. The lib to add sticker, I am using [lib](https://jitpack.io/p/kencheung4/android-StickerView): As the lib itself suggests, I created within my MainActivity the function to add the sticker, however in the example it uses an AddView to display the sticker on the canvas. In my case, that I'm using another lib, how do I display the sticker on my canvas?

Example use lib:

```
// add a stickerImage to canvas
StickerImageView iv_sticker = new StickerImageView(getContext());
iv_sticker.setImageDrawable(((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_sticker )).getDrawable());
canvas.adView(iv_sticker);

// add a stickerText to canvas
StickerTextView tv_sticker = new StickerTextView(getContext());
tv_sticker.setText(“call me baby”);
canvas.addView(tv_sticker);
```

My MainActivity:

```
val inputStream = data.data?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }
val bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
// add a stickerImage to canvas
val iv_sticker = StickerImageView(this@MainActivity)
iv_sticker.imageBitmap = bitMap
canvasEditor.addViewImage(iv_sticker)
```

Meu canvas:

```
<com.divyanshu.draw.widget.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/canvasEditor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewBottom"/>
```

Classe DrawinView the lib Canvas:

```
init {
    mPaint.apply {
        color = mPaintOptions.color
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        strokeWidth = mPaintOptions.strokeWidth
        isAntiAlias = true
    }
}

fun updateBackgroundColor(newColor: Int) {
    mBackgroundColor = newColor
    setBackgroundColor(newColor)
    mBackgroundBitmap = null
}

fun clearCanvas() {
    mLastPaths = mPaths.clone() as LinkedHashMap<MyPath, PaintOptions>
    mPath.reset()
    mPaths.clear()
    invalidate()
}
.
.
.
.
fun toggleEraser() {
    isEraserOn = !isEraserOn
    mPaintOptions.isEraserOn = isEraserOn
    invalidate()
}

fun addViewImage(iv_sticker: StickerView){
    //How show the stiker in my canvas
}
```

Comment: Probably need to put the first library's view in a FrameLayout. Then put another FrameLayout in this parent FrameLayout as well, with the sticker view inside that nested FrameLayout.

Comment: Work!! thanks  Tenfour04